# Issues with Nvidia Display drivers after updates

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and did the latest round of updates, and once completed I was getting to the login screen but it was just blank.  I used Ctrl+Alt+F5 to get to a terminal and saw a message that there were 24 updates that could not be installed automatically so I went and checked the /var/log/unattended-upgrades and saw that they were all Nvidia related.

I did a apt uninstall --purge for everything Nvidia, rebooted and was able to login to the Gui normally, but now if I try to reinstall (even a newer set of Nvidia drivers), when I reboot, the login prompt is missing from the Gui again.  I've been searching a lot of forums and trying to follow the recommended advice, but nothing seems to be helping to resolve the issue.

When I look at the additional drivers through the Gui, I can see all of the Nvidia drivers listed, but can not select them as it says 'this device is using a manually-installed driver'

Let me know what logs or system info would be helpful to diagnose further... I didn't want to fill the question with a bunch of useless info...

@heynnema

DKMS STATUS

```
realtek-rtl8814au, 5.8.5.1~git20210331.bdf80b5, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl8814au, 5.8.5.1~git20210331.bdf80b5, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl88xxau, 5.6.4.2~git20210327.c0ce817, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-rtl88xxau, 5.6.4.2~git20210327.c0ce817, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1035-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1036-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1037-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1039-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1042-gke, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1046-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1049-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1051-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1052-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1053-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1054-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1055-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1056-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1057-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1059-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1061-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1062-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-77-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-80-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-84-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-86-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-88-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-90-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-91-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-92-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-94-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-96-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-97-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 5.2.20, 5.4.0-99-generic, x86_64: built
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: installed
```

DPKG:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                     Arch>
+++-==========================================-===========================-====>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia                      <none>                      <non>
un  libnvidia-compute                          <none>                      <non>
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd6>
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    i386>
rc  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64                460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd6>
rc  libnvidia-compute-460-server:amd64         460.106.00-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd6>
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd6>
un  libnvidia-gl-390                           <none>                      <non>
un  libnvidia-gl-435                           <none>                      <non>
un  libnvidia-gl-440                           <none>                      <non>
un  libnvidia-ml1                              <none>                      <non>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1      amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-43-generic 5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2        amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-44-generic 5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2+1      amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-46-generic 5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1        amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-25-generic 5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1+1      amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1        amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-28-generic 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+2      amd6>
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-30-generic 5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1        amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-41-generic 5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1+1      amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-43-generic 5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2        amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-44-generic 5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2+1      amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-46-generic 5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1        amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-25-generic 5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1+1      amd6>
rc  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1        amd6>
un  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-28-generic <none>                      <non>
un  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-30-generic <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-41-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-43-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-44-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-46-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-25-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-27-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-28-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-30-generic  <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-common                              <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver           <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver           <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev                      <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                          <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-prime                               <none>                      <non>
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver                        <none>                      <non>
lines 1-48/48 (END)
```

Boot:

steve@Teleserver2:~/Downloads$ ls -al /boot

```
total 628968
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Feb 27 17:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root     4096 Dec 12 16:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257734 Jan 19 06:16 config-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257734 Feb  7 09:01 config-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237942 Feb  3 13:16 config-5.4.0-100-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234101 Jan 14  2021 config-5.4.0-1035-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234067 Feb  5  2021 config-5.4.0-1036-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234086 Feb 25  2021 config-5.4.0-1037-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234086 Mar 19  2021 config-5.4.0-1039-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234076 Apr 13  2021 config-5.4.0-1042-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   232428 Feb 10 04:51 config-5.4.0-1063-gke
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Feb 27 17:04 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Feb 22 06:52 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-1063-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 63855128 Feb 27 16:29 initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 63859653 Feb 27 17:51 initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56299942 Feb 27 16:26 initrd.img-5.4.0-100-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55094442 Feb 27 16:26 initrd.img-5.4.0-1035-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55098228 Feb 27 16:26 initrd.img-5.4.0-1036-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55911722 Feb 27 16:26 initrd.img-5.4.0-1037-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55911822 Feb 27 16:25 initrd.img-5.4.0-1039-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55914740 Feb 27 16:25 initrd.img-5.4.0-1042-gke
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29664796 Feb 27 16:25 initrd.img-5.4.0-1063-gke
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Feb 22 06:52 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5959931 Jan 19 06:16 System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5960334 Feb  7 09:01 System.map-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4758018 Feb  3 13:16 System.map-5.4.0-100-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4760662 Jan 14  2021 System.map-5.4.0-1035-gke
-rw-------  1 root root  4761202 Feb  5  2021 System.map-5.4.0-1036-gke
-rw-------  1 root root  4763810 Feb 25  2021 System.map-5.4.0-1037-gke
-rw-------  1 root root  4764039 Mar 19  2021 System.map-5.4.0-1039-gke
-rw-------  1 root root  4764531 Apr 13  2021 System.map-5.4.0-1042-gke
-rw-------  1 root root  4771942 Feb 10 04:51 System.map-5.4.0-1063-gke
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       22 Feb 22 06:52 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-1063-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 10170592 Jan 19 08:43 vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10171040 Feb  7 09:03 vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13664512 Feb  4 12:04 vmlinuz-5.4.0-100-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11666176 Jan 14  2021 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1035-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 11670272 Feb  5  2021 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1036-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 11739904 Feb 25  2021 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1037-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 11739904 Mar 19  2021 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1039-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 11739904 Apr 13  2021 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1042-gke
-rw-------  1 root root 11768064 Feb 10 05:10 vmlinuz-5.4.0-1063-gke
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Feb 22 06:52 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-30-generic
```

steve@Teleserver2:~/Downloads$

Boot:

```
*-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 20:79:18:be:d4:a3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a3334000-a3337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d4:c4:48:15:65
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.5.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:124 memory:a3300000-a331ffff
```

uname -r 5.13.0-30-generic –

The realtek is connected and enabled, but still not working (it doesn't appear)

sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for steve:

```
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 20:79:18:be:d4:a3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a3334000-a3337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d4:c4:48:15:65
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.5.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:124 memory:a3300000-a331ffff
```

LSUSB:

steve@Teleserver2:~/Downloads$ lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 1532:0109 Razer USA, Ltd Lycosa Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:18a3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA MOTHERBOARD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

teve@Teleserver2:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -l *nvidia*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                  Architecture Description
+++-================================-========================-============-==================>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386       390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 i386         NVIDIA libcompute >
un  libnvidia-gl-390                 <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  libnvidia-gl-435                 <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  libnvidia-gl-440                 <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  libnvidia-ml1                    <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-common                    <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-prime                     <none>                   <none>       (no description av>
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>                   <none>       (no description av>

[3]+  Stopped                 sudo dpkg -l *nvidia*
```

Some of them are hanging on...

```
steve@Teleserver2:~/Downloads$ sudo apt purge libnvidia-compute*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-450-server' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-440-server' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-390' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-418' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-430' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-435' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-440' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-450' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-455' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-460' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-465' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-470' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-495' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-510' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-470-server' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-418-server' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Note, selecting 'libnvidia-compute-460-server' for glob 'libnvidia-compute*'
Package 'libnvidia-compute-418' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-390' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libnvidia-compute-390:i386'?
Package 'libnvidia-compute-435' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-440' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-450' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-450-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-455' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-460' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-465' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-470' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-470-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-495' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-510' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-418-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-440-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-460-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libnvidia-compute-430' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

AFTER Running those commands and rebooting

[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XuB3.png)

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                  Architecture Desc>
+++-================================-========================-============-====>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>                   <none>       (no >
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386       390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 i386         NVID>
un  libnvidia-gl-390                 <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  libnvidia-gl-435                 <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  libnvidia-gl-440                 <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  libnvidia-ml1                    <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-common                    <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-prime                     <none>                   <none>       (no >
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>                   <none>       (no >
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

That seemed to do it

```
steve@Teleserver2:~$ sudo dpkg -l *nvidia*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version      Architecture Description
+++-================================-============-============-================>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  libnvidia-gl-390                 <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  libnvidia-gl-435                 <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  libnvidia-gl-440                 <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-common                    <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-prime                     <none>       <none>       (no description >
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>       <none>       (no description >
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

After the last reboot

```
steve@Teleserver2:~$ sudo dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-1063-gke, x86_64: installed
steve@Teleserver2:~$ 


steve@Teleserver2:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for steve: 
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 20:79:18:be:d4:a3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a3334000-a3337fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 10
       serial: 04:d4:c4:48:15:65
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=0.5-4 ip=192.168.5.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:124 memory:a3300000-a331ffff
```

I did the reinstall, and honestly have no idea where I am at this point.... I was able to select the nvidia drivers again on the additional drivers GUI, but it locked me into 640x480, so I chose the Nouveau driver again hoping it would at least give me full resolution... but now I am stuck back on that setting, still in 640x480 and all of the Nvidia drivers are greyed out again...

```
steve@Teleserver2:~$ dpkg -l *nvidia*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/tri>
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version       >
+++-==========================================-==============>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia                      <none>        >
un  libnvidia-compute                          <none>        >
rc  libnvidia-compute-465:amd64                465.19.01-0ubu>
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                510.47.03-0ubu>
un  libnvidia-gl-390                           <none>        >
un  libnvidia-gl-435                           <none>        >
un  libnvidia-gl-440                           <none>        >
un  libnvidia-ml1                              <none>        >
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.13.0-30-generic 5.13.0-30.33~2>
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-510-5.13.0-30-generic 5.13.0-30.33~2>
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-30-generic  5.13.0-30.33~2>
un  nvidia-384                                 <none>        >
un  nvidia-common                              <none>        >
un  nvidia-compute-utils                       <none>        >

[1]+  Stopped                 dpkg -l *nvidia*
```

Also infi -F shows the following:

```
Graphics: Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] driver: nvidia v: 510.47.03 Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev,nouveau unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 640x480~73Hz OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6
```

If I could just get off 640x480 resolution and get my other monitors working I would be happy for now...

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134477/discussion-on-question-by-zanetampa911-issues-with-nvidia-display-drivers-after) which will hopefully be more convenient

Comment: @heynnema I reinstalled the 510 driver from the .run file before I saw your comment about renaming the xorg.conf file....  I don't know if that had a negative impact or if it existed before I did the install...  

After I got back into the graphical display with 640x480,  I checked and there was a file in the etc/X11 folder....

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days of fighting with driver updates, and a million other things, I opened a case with Nvidia's developer network https://forums.developer.nvidia.com and they were able to diagnose the issue as a missing monitors.xml file in the `/var/lib/gdm3/.config` folder.

I had to disconnect all but one of my monitors and reboot.  At which point everything looked normal. I then deleted the `monitors.xml` file in my `~/.config` folder, reconnected my monitors and set them up through the display settings menu, which created a new `monitors.xml` file in the `~/.config` folder. I copied that over to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config` folder and rebooted and everything looks good!!!

Thanks @heynnema for all of your help trying to help me diagnose this mess.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have a monitors.xml file, but I don't have 3 monitors either. I wonder how that file got changed with just doing Software Updates?